# Couchbase - Can the N1QL DP4 release handle the stale option being set on a query?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have been running some tests using the DP4 release of N1QL.

It seems that if I write to the database (save a document) I can access it by key straight away, but if I run a query to find it by the document type and another matching value it doesn't come back in the results for between 1 and 10 seconds.

After this time has passed, the query returns the expected result.

I have seen the issue raised here: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-10944

The issue says it is resolved in DP4 but there is no confirmation of this or documentation on how to use the new feature.

Has anybody figured out how to do this or could one of the Couchbase developers lend a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes but that feature is currently not available via the N1QL shell and you will need to use the HTTP REST API directly to pass those parameters.

e.g.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8093/query/service -d 'statement=select * from default&scan_consistency=REQUEST_PLUS'
```

By setting the scan_consistency parameter to 'REQUEST PLUS', N1QL will set stale=false internally for the view scan.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using the Node.js library "couchnode"?